# Multi mapping: not the same results

Tags: c#, .net

I have two attemps of multi mapping between three types:

init:

```
var users = multi.Read<User>().ToArray();
var uroles = multi.Read<UserRoleRow>().ToArray();
var roles = multi.Read<Role>().ToArray();
```

first try (success):

```
foreach (var u in users)
    u.Roles = roles.Where(r => uroles.Any(ur => ur.RoleId == r.RoleId 
        && ur.UserId == u.UserId)).AsQueryable();
```

second try (fault):

```
foreach (var u in users)
    u.Roles = roles.Where(r => uroles.Contains(new UserRoleRow {
        RoleId = r.RoleId,
        UserId = u.UserId
    })).AsQueryable();
```

Why second try doesn't work and what's the better practise of that? Ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you override the `UserRoleRow.Equals` method?

By default C# will only look if the references are equal. An object containing the same data is not necessary the same object.

For instance when using:

```
public class Foo {

   int bar;

   public Foo (int bar) {
       this.bar = bar;
   }


}
```

will not satisfy the constraint `new Foo(2) == new Foo(2)`, however:

```
public class Foo {

   int bar;

   public Foo (int bar) {
       this.bar = bar;
   }

   public override bool Equals (object other) {
       return (other is Foo && ((Foo) other).bar == this.bar);
   }


}
```

will do.

Comment: No, i didn't override

Comment: If you try the example I've demonstrated (creating two objects with the same values), it will probably result in false. Since the `Contains` method uses these methods, the `Contains` method will return `false`. You can define an `Equals` method as shown in the example.

Comment: Yeap, forgot about default `IEqualityComparer`, everything fine